# Cognos Export / Import reports Properties

Tags: pdf, properties, import, export, cognos

I have exported my public reports from productions and imported them into training environment.

But the default format of each report did not copy over along, it was meant to be set as PDF, but when i imported to training ENV it went to html.. this would be find if there were 100+ reports to change.

Are there any options to select when importing/exporting to import the properties also? 
Or anyway to bulk change the default display to pdf?

Thanks jimmy.

Comment: You can set the default report rendering at the user level i.e. each user can set their default to PDF - will that help?

Comment: how do i set the report rendering at user level?

I have upgraded to cognos 10.1 now and facing similar problems where all my reports are set to HTML...there has to be a way to set for ALL reports to run as PDF by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a users default report rendering to PDF:

1. Log in to Cognos
2. At the top right next to the house icon you'll see a little person icon
3. Click the icon and select My Preferences
4. Change Report Format to PDF

Any object not specifically overriden will automatically render as PDF.

Comment: AMAZING!!Thank you! sorted now :)